# Getting data into templates without helper functions

Tags: meteor

What is the difference between:

```
  Session.set("sessionclickcount",1);
  Template.hello.clickcount = Session.get("sessionclickcount");
```

and

```
  Session.set("sessionclickcount",1);
  Template.hello.clickcount = function()
  {
    return Session.get("sessionclickcount");
  };
```

I try to update the template data later by updating the session variable using the below code:

```
  Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      Session.set("sessionclickcount",
        Session.get("sessionclickcount")+1);
    }
  });
```

First method fails, html does not change. The second succeeds. Why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers in meteor need to return functions. This is because the function is run in a context and allows meteor to keep track of dependencies.

These dependencies then help meteor know the template needs to be redrawn with new data.

If you use `Template.hello.clickcount = Session.get("sessionclickcount");`, the render engine (spark) doesn't get any dependencies from this that's why it doesn't change. It doesn't know it has to redraw it.

Comment: When OP said "First method fails..." what he meant was, "the value doesn't change" rather "than nothing was displayed".  In this case, the value '1' will always be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Helpers in meteor can be either functions or constant values.

From [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#templates):

> Helpers can also be used to pass in constant data.
>
> // Works fine with {{#each sections}}
>   Template.report.sections = ["Situation", "Complication", "Resolution"];

In your case you are setting the helper to a constant value, 1, because it is the value of the session field at the time this line of javascript was executed:

`Template.hello.clickcount = Session.get("sessionclickcount");`